# Implicitly naming nodes inside a matrix in TikZ (quotes syntax)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following picture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc,matrix,quotes}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     \matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,
                  every node/.style={anchor=west}, 
                  node distance=5mm,inner sep=0.5mm,draw]
     {
       |(ping)| ping\\
       foo bar\\
       |(todo)| todo\\
     };

     \draw[thick,red,->] (ping.west) -- (todo.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can I somehow avoid the verbose "|(ping)| ping" syntax? I would like to write directly ping, (ping) or ["ping"], or something like that.

I am aware of the (a-1-1) syntax, but it is even less readable by a human.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is whether you can avoid the duplication, i.e. type `ping` only once, the answer is affirmative.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc,matrix,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[s/.style={alias=#1,execute at begin node=#1}]
     \matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,
                  every node/.style={anchor=west}, 
                  node distance=5mm,inner sep=0.5mm,draw]
     {
        |[s=ping]| \\
       foo bar\\
        |[s=todo]|\\
     };

     \draw[thick,red,->] (ping.west) -- (todo.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether or not this is more elegant than not to name the nodes and use `\draw[thick,red,->] (a-1-1.west) -- (a-3-1.east);` instead is a different question.